# rails 4 simple form include_blank still sending empty attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, modelattribute

I have the following form setup:

```
= simple_form_for(@job, url: job_payment_path, html: { id: 'payment-processor-form' }) do |j|
  div[class='row']
    div[class='col-md-12']
      div[class='panel panel-default']
        div[class='panel-heading']
          h3[class='panel-title']
            |Total Cost
        div[class='panel-body']
          h2[class='job-cost' data-initial = "#{job_base_price}"]
            = number_to_currency(job_base_price)
        div[class='panel-heading']
          h3[class='panel-title']
            |Have a coupon?
        div[class='panel-body']
          div[class='row-inline']
            div[class='row-block row-block-one']
              = j.simple_fields_for :coupon_attributes, @job.coupon do |c|
                = c.input_field :code, maxlength: 50, id: 'coupon-code', class: 'form-control', data: { 'initial' => 0 }, include_blank: false
            div[class='row-block']
              button[type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='coupon-verify' ]
                |Verify
            p[class='help-hint']
              = t('simple_form.hints.coupon.code')

  div[class='row']
    div[class='col-md-12']
      = j.button :button, type: 'button', class: 'btn-primary text-uppercase', id: 'purchase-job' do
        = job_posting_button_step_label
```

When this form submits, I am seeing the following attributes:

[image]

This is not right.

I would expect the coupon code to be nil, not "".

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two things:

first:
`:include_blank` is an option for select fields, it skips the generation of a blank `option` tag at the beginning. `code` is an input field. If you want to force an input value, try `required: true`.

second:
form values are sent to the server as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Empty imput fields are sent as i.e. `job[coupon_attributes][code]=`. There is no distinction between an empty string and no value.
The convention in Rails is to interpret all input values as string (and typecast later when assigning values to models). So an empty value is always returned as `''`.